# WEBSERVER JSON API LOCALHOST

Tags: json, node.js, localhost, bots

I want setup a simple webserver using JSON API([I Followed this tutorial](https://community.chatfuel.com/t/add-serverside-logic-to-your-bot-with-just-10-lines-of-javascript/3543?u=derby)).I have in this directory (*C:\xampp\htdocs\server*) 2 files:

- server.js
- node_modules(folder)

***server.js***

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Chatfuel Bot-Server listening on port 3000...');
});

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    var jsonResponse = [];
    jsonResponse.push({ "text": "Hi. " + (Math.random() * 5 + 1).toFixed(0) + " is a lucky number..." });
    res.send(jsonResponse);
});
```

So what is happening in the background?

After launched via terminal: node server.js
If the server gets a request it invokes code lines 8 to 12.
But it doesn't works! why?
[Screens and more info here.](https://community.chatfuel.com/t/add-serverside-logic-to-your-bot-with-just-10-lines-of-javascript/3543/10?u=derby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're serving node from your local computer, and the chatbot testing service is trying to connect to that running instance of node, and it cannot connect to your localhost.

In the example, they've used digital ocean to deploy the node application. Therefore, the running API is available at some real IP address.

So, if you want to do what they've done, deploy your node app somewhere and expose that particular deployment's IP to your testing framework, and then it should work.

Comment: It's possibile. I fixed that wit Ngrok, but the best way is to use a virtual server.